# Hide datgrid auto added columns

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

Below xaml datagrid is giving me two extra columns, before the Image column and after the price column. How can I disable it?

```
<DataGrid Name="dgProductList" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="18" 
                                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"      
                                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Image Height="10" Width="10" Source="{Binding Picture}" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Item" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" Header="Price" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Add an itemssource binding in your DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgProductList" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontSize="18"
                              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" MouseDoubleClick="dgProductList_MouseDoubleClick">
```

Codebehind:

```
public class Product : NotificationObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>
    {
        new Product {Name = "test1"},
        new Product {Name = "test2"},
    };

    DataContext = this;

    InitializeComponent();
}

private void dgProductList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Products.Add(new Product { Name = "test x" });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to use datagridtemplate, so I have to assign a comlumn.

Comment: yes, that's no problem, i have just shortened the xaml to show only the part that changed. You can setup the columns normally. But instead of adding a new item directly to the datagrid, you add it to the Products collection and because the itemssource is bound to this collection, the new item will appear in the grid

Comment: You can use your datagridtemplate and ItemsSource binding.

Answer (score 1):

there are no extra columns if I just copy and paste your xaml. Maybe there is some code in the codebehind file that creates the columns?

Comment: Yes it only happens when I add row from code behind. I am using something like this this.dgProductList.Items.Add(product); product is a model object, which has more attributes then the datagrid.

Comment: you should try to avoid adding items directly to Controls. I don't know what the problem is because i could achieve everything with databinding. See my new answer for an example

Comment: I thaought I am using AutoGenerateColumns="False".